# No insight into what is happening with push notifications

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

I wanted to know is there is there anything in works that gives info on what happened to push notifications from service workers ?

GCM has it in play console where exact journey of a push is given. 
We are getting message ids for most of the active subscribers but when we are not getting impressions in our analytics saying it reached the device.

Can a system be built which explains what happened to push notification is given. 
Also can information be passed if there any cache clearing or anything that took away the device token of that device ? That would be really helpful as then we can understand what is causing that the device tokens to go away.

Right now our stats are 400K active subscribers for which we get valid message ids and only 50K impressions for them even when the push expiry is 10 days. This is a really sad ratio. We also have put on our entire website https and have put a mechanism to get back their dev tokens if they visit again and we see we dont have their token even though they had subscribed earlier.